# How do I access an inline element inside a loop in lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to screen scrape values from a website.

```
# get the raw HTML
fruitsWebsite = lxml.html.parse( "http://pagetoscrape.com/data.html" )

# get all divs with class fruit 
fruits = fruitsWebsite.xpath( '//div[@class="fruit"]' )

# Print the name of this fruit (obtained from an <em> in the fruit div)
for fruit in fruits:
    print fruit.xpath('//li[@class="fruit"]/em')[0].text
```

However, the Python interpreter complains that 0 is an out of bounds iterator. That's interesting because I am sure that the element exists. What is the proper way to access the inside `<em>` element with lxml?

Comment: Are you able to provide a sample of html to run this against that demonstrates the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works for me with my test file.

```
#test.py
import lxml.html

# get the raw HTML
fruitsWebsite = lxml.html.parse('test.html')

# get all divs with class fruit 
fruits = fruitsWebsite.xpath('//div[@class="fruit"]')

# Print the name of this fruit (obtained from an <em> in the fruit div)
for fruit in fruits:
    #Use a relative path so we don't find ALL of the li/em elements several times. Note the .//
    for item in fruit.xpath('.//li[@class="fruit"]/em'):
        print(item.text)


#Alternatively
for item in fruit.xpath('//div[@class="fruit"]//li[@class="fruit"]/em'):
    print(item.text)
```

Here is the html file I used to test again.  If this doesn't work for the html you're testing again, you'll need to post a sample file that fails as I requested in the comments above.

```
<html>
<body>
Blah blah
<div>Ignore me</div>
<div>Outer stuff
    <div class='fruit'>Some <em>FRUITY</em> stuff.
    <ol>
        <li class='fruit'><em>This</em> should show</li>
        <li><em>Super</em> Ignored LI</li>
        <li class='fruit'><em>Rawr</em> Hear it roar.</li>
    </ol>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='fruit'><em>Super</em> fruity website of awesome</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You definitely will get too many results with the code you originally posted (the inner loop will search the entire tree rather than the subtree for each "fruit").  The error you're describing doesn't make much sense unless your input is different than what I understood.

Comment: Thanks! That's a problem I'm getting sometimes too. Sometimes, it works, but the results are repetitive (like one fruit appears 4 times). Why is that? Why am I searching the entire tree in the inner loop?

Comment: When you have //li/......, it is searching the entire tree from the root.  You're doing this for each fruit DIV that you find.  So, 3 fruit divs and 5 fruit li would mean you'd see all 5 fruit li entries 3 times.  In my code, I have .//li which means search relative to the current node in the tree.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't xpath being called by `fruit`? So isn't `fruit` fruit the relative root in this case?

Comment: `fruit` is just a node in the tree.  Even while looking at the `fruit` node in question, the root of the tree is still going to be the full body.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense now. I solved my problem by the way - 2 fruits out of 2141 used `<strong>` instead of `<em>`. Fruity problem this was. However, you solved another problem I had, so I really appreciate it!